# how to increase tombstone_failure_threshold value

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I would like to increase the `tombstone_failure_threshold` value in `cassandra.yaml` file, By default the value is `100K`

I am not sure about the value to set.

I have gone through some documentations, I saw like decreasing default `gc_grace_seconds` is `864000` (10 days). If your `TTL` data is set to `6 days` then you might want to change `gc_grace_seconds` to `604800 (7 days)` to remove tombstones sooner. But I am not setting `TTL` for my data. If I decrease `gc_grace_seconds` value, will it effect the `tombstone_failure_threshold` or better to change the `tombstone_failure_threshold` value in `cassandra.yaml` file?

```
`CREATE TABLE test.topics (
 topic_name text PRIMARY KEY,
 latest_time_stamp double
 ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of "DESC TABLE tablename" from your cluster for the table in concern"? If you aren't setting TTL and have more than 100K tombstones, then there is some very heavy deletes going on.

Comment: added `desc table` info

Comment: So as you mentioned you aren’t setting time to live on table. So it’s definitely deletes. Increasing the limits further will severely impact performance. So be aware of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- tombstone_warn_threshold (default: 1000): if the number of tombstones scanned by a query exceeds this number Cassandra will log a warning (which will likely be propagating to your monitoring system and send you an alert).
- **tombstone_failure_threshold** (default: 100000): if the number of tombstones scanned by a query exceeds this number Cassandra will abort the query. The is a mechanism to prevent one or more nodes from running out of memory and crashing.

These values should only be changed upwards if you are really confident about the memory use patterns in your cluster.